# How to make React router without pound sign?

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React. My situation is like this:

I have a page in React, but React browser history makes all url must have a # sign, so the url is like this: http://www.somedomain.com/path/#/login. I need to send this url to a third party url for callback, like this: http://www.thirdparty.com/verify?callback=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.somedomain.com%2Fpath%2F%23%2Flogin. The problem is that they do not allow # in the url. The only url format they allow is like http://www.somedomain.com/path/login, so then they will add some parameter after the url, finally they will callback http://www.somedomain.com/path/login?code=something&state=somestate.

I am wondering how can I achieve this? Every possible solution is accepted, including Apache or Nginx url rewriting, not limit to React router solution. Thank you in advance!

My code is as below:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
  }

  render() {
    const appHistory = useRouterHistory(createHashHistory)({ queryKey: false });
    return (
      <Router history={appHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Main}>
          <IndexRoute component={Home} />
          <Route path="login" component={Login} />
          <Route path="mypics" component={MyPics} onEnter={requireAuth} />
        </Route>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [`browserHistory`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md#browserhistory) as history provider.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from "react-router";

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router history={browserHistory}>
                <Route path="/" component={...}>
                    ...
                </Route>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

// Render the main component into the dom
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Comment: Thank you! That is the correct way. However I still love the hashhistory, because I found that with hashhistory my page will not send any request to server, but with browserhistory, it will send request to server, it seems broke the single page application behavior. I personally don't like that. I will try to use another special url for callback, then redirect back to my hashhistory. Thanks anyway!